# Laravel 5.5 Scheduler commands with cron

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron

Any help on this issue would be most appreciated.

I have 15 time based tasks running at specific times.  It is important that they run at these times as they build their data based on the first cron task that runs.  Here is an example:

```
$schedule->command( 'task:build one' )->cron( '2/5 * * * *' );
$schedule->command( 'task:build two' )->cron( '3/15 * * * *' );
$schedule->command( 'task:build three' )->cron( '3 * * * *' );
$schedule->command( 'task:build four' )->cron( '4 */12 * * *' );
...
```

Using task:two as the example the issue is as follows:

task:two uses the results in the database generated by task:one and stores to a different table.  The table used by task:one is only EVER read by the other tasks and never written to.  So:

task:one runs and takes less than a minute.
task:two starts one minute later.

On rare occasions (maybe up to 8 times a week, seems random) task:two is delayed so long that task:one manages to run again (5 minutes later) and add an extra row in its table, so by the time task:two gets to the data it has more than it needs.

From my own research so far:

1. There are no sql deadlock issues, as each task only writes to a table specific to itself and I cannot see any mysql error logs.
2. The database is approx. 5GIG, running on a cheap $20 Digital Ocean server.
3. From the 15 tasks it seems that some tasks are effected more than others and some never seem effected.

I am not a dev ops guy and I am trying to establish if this is a Laravel issue, possibly due to my bad implementation, or a server issue.

I hope that describes the issue well enough for assistance but if not please let me know what extra information you require.

Comment: Any PHP errors? Do you have log output from each and every step of your tasks to see where it's slowing down? Does task two always finish, even if slowly? What's the server load like at the time? Could that be slowing it down? What's different between task two and all the other tasks that might cause only that one to occassionally run slowly?

Comment: No PHP errors at all.  All exceptions are sent to Slack so that I know and I get none.  Yes, all tasks finish and I have a one line log for each task with a timestamp of when they ended.  I can also see from the DB created_at that they are being delayed.

Comment: @fubar The server load at these times seems OK also.  Of the 15 tasks approx 4 of them seem effected.  And it seems random.  They are not at the same time.

Comment: Have you renamed the tasks for this question, or is this really a single task:build command that takes a parameters (one, two, three, four)?

Comment: It is a single command used yes that uses different tables each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel feature called task overlapping using command 
`$schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping(10);`
To know more here is the link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps go through this

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: withoutOverlapping() will not help on this occasion but thank you.